# El wp_schedule_single_event no funciona. Quiero que el cron ejecute obtener_articulo_y_publicar en el tiempo que hay en la variable $tiempo_publicacio

Tags: php, wordpress

El titulo explica bastante bien lo que quiero. No hay mucho mas contexto. Por alguna razón el wp_schedule_single_event no funciona en mi código. La variable donde esta el tiempo está en formato UNIX. Antes usé un cron que ejecutaba la función cada 1 minuto pensando que no pasaría nada porque se dejaría de ejecutar después de que evalué que horas no es <= a 0. Pero no funcionaba bien. Tardaba en publicar la primera y después de que la publicaba todas las demás se posteaban con un minuto de diferencia, sin respetar el tiempo de espera de cada articulo.

```
function suma_segundos(){
    global $filename;
    // Variable para almacenar la suma
    $suma = 0;
    // Verificar si el archivo existe y no está vacío
    if (file_exists($filename) && filesize($filename) > 0) {
        // Abrir el archivo en modo lectura
        $archivo = fopen($filename, 'r');
        
        if ($archivo) {
            while (($linea = fgets($archivo)) !== false) {
                // Dividir la línea en partes usando '||' como separador
                $datos = explode('||', $linea);
                
                // Verificar si hay al menos una parte
                if (isset($datos[0])) {
                    // Convertir la primera parte a un número y sumarlo a la variable $suma
                    $primer_dato = (int)$datos[0];
                    $suma += $primer_dato;
                }
            }
            // Cerrar el archivo
            fclose($archivo);
            return $suma;
        } else {
            echo 'No se pudo abrir el archivo.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'El archivo no existe o está vacío.';
    }
}
// HTML para la página de ajustes
function ammd_settings_page() {
    global $filename;

    if (isset($_POST['titulo']) && !empty($_POST['titulo']) && isset($_POST['prompt']) && !empty($_POST['prompt'])) {
         // Limpiar el título y el prompt
        $titulo_clean = sanitize_text_field($_POST['titulo']);
        $prompt_clean = sanitize_textarea_field($_POST['prompt']);

        // Generar un valor aleatorio en horas entre 8 y 20
        $valor_en_horas = 120;//rand(60, 120); //Valor en horas

        // Convertir el valor en horas a segundos
        $valor_en_segundos = $valor_en_horas; //* 3600; 

        //$suma = suma_segundos();
        //$valor_en_segundos+=$suma;

        // Obtener el tiempo actual en formato Unix (time())
        $tiempo_actual = time();

        // Crear la línea de contenido a agregar al archivo
        $nuevo_contenido = $valor_en_segundos . '||' . $tiempo_actual . '||' . str_replace("\n", ' ', $titulo_clean) . '||' . str_replace("\n", ' ', $prompt_clean) . " \n";

        $tiempo_publicacion = time() + $valor_en_segundos + 20;

        // Programar un cron job individual para este artículo con el tiempo de espera específico
        $error=wp_schedule_single_event($tiempo_publicacion, 'obtener_articulo_y_publicar', array($titulo_clean, $prompt_clean));
        echo('<h1>'.$error.'</h1>');
        sleep(2);


        file_put_contents($filename, $nuevo_contenido, FILE_APPEND);

        echo '<div class="updated"><p>Título, Prompt y Valores de tiempo agregados con éxito!</p></div>';
   
    }

    // El código HTML para la página de ajustes
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h2>Automatizador de artículos</h2>';
    echo '<form method="post" action="">';
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th scope="row"><label for="titulo">Agregar Título</label></th>';
    echo '<td><input name="titulo" type="text" id="titulo" value="" class="regular-text" required></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th scope="row"><label for="prompt">Agregar Prompt</label></th>';
    echo '<td><textarea name="prompt" id="prompt" rows="5" cols="50" required></textarea></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button button-primary" value="Guardar Título y Prompt"></p>';
    echo '</form>';

    // Nueva sección para mostrar los artículos y prompts en cola
    echo '<h2>Cola de Artículos y Prompts</h2>';
    echo '<table class="form-table">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Título</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Prompt</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Tiempo de espera</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';

    // Leer el archivo y separarlo en líneas
    $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $flag = True;
    if (!empty($lines)) {
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            list($horas2,$tiempo_registro ,$titulo,$prompt) = explode('||', $line, 4);
            if ($flag){
                //Logica para calcular el tiempo de la cuenta atras.
                $tiempo = time();
                $tiempo_resta = $tiempo-$tiempo_registro;
                $horas = $horas2 - $tiempo_resta;
                $flag = False;


            }else{
                $horas+=$horas2;
            }
            // Separar cada línea en título y prompt
            
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . esc_html($titulo) . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . esc_html($prompt) . '</td>';
            echo '<td><span class="countdown" data-tiempo="' . esc_attr($horas) . '"></span></td>';
            echo '</tr>';

        }
    } else {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="2">No hay artículos o prompts en la cola.</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';  // Cierre del div "wrap"
    echo '<script>
    function startCountdown(element, totalSeconds) {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            var hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
            var minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 3600) / 60);
            var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
            var formattedTime = formatTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
            element.textContent = formattedTime;
            if (totalSeconds <= 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                element.textContent = "Cuenta regresiva finalizada.";
            }
            totalSeconds--;
        }, 1000);
    }

    function formatTime(hours, minutes, seconds) {
        return String(hours).padStart(2, "0") + ":" + String(minutes).padStart(2, "0") + ":" + String(seconds).padStart(2, "0");
    }

    var countdownElements = document.querySelectorAll(".countdown");
    countdownElements.forEach(function(element) {
        var totalSeconds = parseInt(element.getAttribute("data-tiempo"));
        startCountdown(element, totalSeconds);
    });
    </script>';

    }







// Al activar el plugin, crea el archivo si no existe
function ammd_activate() {
    global $filename;
    if(!file_exists($filename)) {
        touch($filename);
    }
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'ammd_activate');






function obtener_articulo_y_publicar() {
    global $filename;

    $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $flag = True;
    if (!empty($lines)) {
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            list($horas2,$tiempo_registro ,$titulo,$prompt) = explode('||', $line, 4);
            if ($flag){
                //Logica para calcular el tiempo de la cuenta atras.
                $tiempo = time();
                $tiempo_resta = $tiempo-$tiempo_registro;

                $linea_unida = implode('||', [$horas2, $tiempo_registro, $titulo, $prompt]);
                $linea_reemplazo = implode('||', [$horas2, time(), $titulo, $prompt]);
                reemplazar_linea_en_archivo($filename,$linea_unida,$linea_reemplazo);

                $horas = $horas2 - $tiempo_resta;
                $flag = False;
                if ($horas <= 0) {                
                    // Obtener el artículo, título y prompt desde el archivo .txt
                    list($titulo, $articulo) = obtener_articulo_y_titulo();

                    // Si no hay título o artículo, detener la ejecución
                    if (empty($titulo) || empty($articulo)) {

                        return; // Detiene la ejecución si no hay títulos

                    }

                    // Obtener fotos relacionadas con el título del artículo
                    $foto_url_inicio = obtener_foto_unsplash('marketing'); // Ajusta el término según tus necesidades
                    $foto_url_medio = obtener_foto_unsplash('business');  // Ajusta el término según tus necesidades

                    // Generar el código HTML para las fotos
                    $foto_html_inicio = "<!-- wp:image -->\n<figure class=\"wp-block-image\"><img src=\"$foto_url_inicio\" alt=\"\"/></figure>\n<!-- /wp:image -->";
                    $foto_html_medio = "<!-- wp:image -->\n<figure class=\"wp-block-image\"><img src=\"$foto_url_medio\" alt=\"\"/></figure>\n<!-- /wp:image -->";

                    // Dividir el artículo en dos partes
                    $article_parts = explode("\n", $articulo);
                    $halfway_point = floor(count($article_parts) / 2);

                    $first_half = array_slice($article_parts, 0, $halfway_point);
                    $second_half = array_slice($article_parts, $halfway_point);

                    $first_half_content = '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $first_half) . '</p>';
                    $second_half_content = '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $second_half) . '</p>';

                    // Combinar las fotos y el artículo en el contenido del post
                    $post_content = $foto_html_inicio . "\n\n" . $first_half_content . "\n\n" . $foto_html_medio . "\n\n" . $second_half_content;

                    // Argumentos del post
                    $post_args = array(
                        'post_title'    => $titulo,
                        'post_content'  => $post_content,
                        'post_status'   => 'publish',
                        'post_author'   => 1,
                        'post_type'     => 'post'
                    );

                    // Insertar el post

                    $id_post=wp_insert_post($post_args);

                    asignar_imagen_destacada($id_post,$foto_url_inicio);
                    // Eliminar la primera línea del archivo para evitar duplicados
                    $lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
                    if (!empty($lines)) {
                        unset($lines[0]);
                        file_put_contents($filename, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```